# Best way to program varying cost of child admissions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a program in which visitors would select how many kids they have, then provide their ages. I would then need to calculate their total cost according to the kid's ages and cost for each age.

I assume I would need to serialize a hash in order to get this data into the ActiveRecord but I'm confused as to how I would read this hash and calculate it against the hash provided by the user.

Is serialize the way to go with this particular problem or is there a better way?

Comment: `serialize`, in my experience, causes problems with relations. Aha! relations, so I would recommend a child table, which `belongs_to` this one.

Comment: You can create a hashmap for age and cost inside your model, why do you want it to store in database. Then you can easily calculate the cost from the hash you get from user.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does recognize Arrays as a data type. So you could go that route. Though, you might want to separate out this data into it's own table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  ...


class Children < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
  ...
```

And table schema something like:

```
table: users
  |id|fname|lname|...

table: children
  |id|name|user_id|...
```

So now it doesn't matter how many children each user has, you will always have a simple interface for adding, deleting and querying them.

```
c = User.first
c.children   #returns array of Child objects.
```

Serialize is certain a way to go, but a model and a table allows you to be much more DB agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I think, hash serialization is not quite a RoR way.
Instead, having ActiveRecord model for a cost by age

```
AgeCost
--------
age: int
cost: decimal
```

one can easily find a total cost

```
kids_ages = [4, 7, 10]

total_cost = 0
kids_ages.each do |kid_age|
  age_cost = AgeCost.find_by_age(kid_age)
  total_cost += age_cost.cost if age_cost
end
```